# Insert random number in column MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called videos in MySQL database. It have column called likes and it have about 500 records in it. Column likes currently have 0 values in all rows. I want set random value for that column like 10,50,11,23 etc. between 10 to 100. I am new in PHP and does not know how I can do it.
I have tried like below query

```
UPDATE videos SET likes = 10;
```

But it's setting 10 for all rows, instead I want random number there.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function:

```
UPDATE videos SET likes = FLOOR(RAND()*(100-10)+10);
```

`RAND()` will generate a number from 0 to 1. Simply multiply it by the range of your options, and add the initial low value (In this case 10). Use `FLOOR()` on the final result, to round it down to the nearest integer:

Comment: Thanks, Its working like charm.

Comment: You're assuming that `likes` isn't already an integer field @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You should state this in your answer then, that it assumes MySQL will do an implicit conversion from float to integer.

Comment: I still think we should allow a half a like. Maybe I only like the video half as much as another one. @TimBiegeleisen.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that...but this breaks suit with sites like Facebook and Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, you are correct. I've updated my answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dae055/1

Comment: It works well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `RAND()`:

```
UPDATE videos
SET likes = FLOOR(RAND()*(100-10+1)+10);
```

Note that using `FLOOR` here is necessary, because the `RAND()` function generates a uniformly distributed *floating* point value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

use Rand to generate number

```
   UPDATE videos SET likes = FLOOR(10 + RAND() * (100-10));
```